# How do I close a Solana Account?

Tags: account, rent

We can easily close PDAs to redeem their rent to their owner, however what I'm wondering is can the same be done for a *normal, on-curve* Solana account? From what I can see once you've sent the minimum rent-exempt balance to a new account, those funds are stuck there forever. Is there a way I can get those funds back out by closing the new account?

(I'm looking for a programmatic solution, preferably in Typescript)

Comment: You don't even need to send min rent exemption fee to normal account if you would like to use it as a signer only but you can use fee payer separately.

Comment: That's true, but I'm asking assuming I have sent the minimum amount already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For accounts owned by the system programs, which we normally call "wallets", you just need to `system_instruction::transfer` the funds out of it.

For accounts owned by other programs, there's no generic way to "close" them and recover the lamports. The program *must* expose a way to retrieve those lamports.

For example, the native stake program allows you to `withdraw` all of the lamports in a deactivated staked account, which closes it. On the other hand, the SPL token program exposes the `close_account` instruction.

All that to say, you need bindings into the program, and one of the instructions in the program must allow you to retrieve rent-exempt lamports. There is no general way to do this.

Side note: I think it would be a great general interface to add, so programs can all implement the same instruction, and that way you can close any account! Feel free to suggest an interface sRFC for `close_account`, similar to Anatoly's at https://forum.solana.com/t/srfc-00015-interfaces/267

Answer (score 0):

In Anchor/Rust you simply set the account to "close" and specify where the rent will go:

```
    #[account(mut, close = rent_destination)]
    some_account: Account<'info>,
```

In TS you can't close a PDA, since only the program has authority to transfer those funds, but you can close a Token Account, for example, with `createCloseAccountInstruction` or `closeAccount` (from the spl-token library).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but to be clear - I know how to close a PDA (including Token Accounts) already. I'm asking if there's a way to close an on-curve account.

Comment: Who would be the owner in that scenario? Usually a program opens the account and owns it, so the program is also responsible for closing the account.

Comment: I'm thinking more in an analog to how `selfdestruct` works over in Ethereum land - the account can call this on itself using a tx it signed and the SystemProgram (since that owns every account not owned by a different program)  and specify a different account that should receive its rent

Answer (score 0):

Check this out this example of close account

https://yihau.github.io/solana-web3-demo/advanced/token/close-account.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but to be clear - I know how to close a PDA (including Token Accounts) already. I'm asking if there's a way to close an on-curve account.